# Python short-hand for HTML insertion

Tags: python, chameleon

In the documentation we find this:

> ### [`${...} operator`](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#operator)
>
> The ${...} notation is short-hand for **text insertion**. The Python-expression inside the braces is evaluated and the result included in the output (all inserted text is escaped by default):
>
> ```
>  <div id="section-${index + 1}">
>     ${content}
>  </div>
> ```
>
> To escape this behavior, prefix the notation with a backslash character: `\${...}`.

How can I render the `content` value as HTML instead of text?

Comment: I don't understand your title. This appears to be a question about escaping in Chameleon, not "Python text insertion".

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right. I edited it: I am looking for html insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid escaping, use the `structure:` prefix:

```
<div>${structure: content}</div>
```

You can also pass an object with a `__html__` method:

> Note that if an object implements the `__html__` method, the result of
>   this method will be inserted as-is (without XML escaping).

**Update:**

As requested, here is an example of how I think the `__html__` method should work. Note that I'm not a Chameleon user and that this code untested :)

```
class Unescaped(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __html__(self):
        return self.value
```

In your template:

```
<div>${ Unescaped(content) }</div>
```

Comment: You can use chameleon.utils.Markup, which is a slightly cleaner version of the same concept. Just return Markup(...) from your view in places where you would normally use a raw string if you don't want Chameleon to escape it.